# Glade layout not reflecting when compiled / GTK_IS_APPLICATION assertion failed

Tags: c, xml, linux, gtk, glade

Running through chapter 10's tutorial code in [the GTK+ book](http://www.gtkbook.com/), I've run into the following inconsistency between glade and the interpreted output. What it looks like to me is that the toolbar (which is the 1st element in a vertically aligned box) is set to expand, but I specifically disabled that and instead enabled it for the `GtkTreeView`, which is the 3rd element in that same vbox.

Glade:

[image: glade screenshot]

App:

[image: app screenshot]

This is the relevant Glade XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- Generated with glade 3.18.3 -->
<interface>
  <requires lib="gtk+" version="3.12"/>
      [...]
      <object class="GtkToolbar" id="toolbar1">
        <property name="visible">True</property>
        <property name="can_focus">False</property>
        <property name="margin_bottom">123</property>
        <property name="toolbar_style">both</property>
        <property name="show_arrow">False</property>
        <property name="icon_size">2</property>
      </object>
      <packing>
        <property name="expand">False</property>
        <property name="fill">False</property>
        <property name="position">0</property>
      </packing>
      [...]
</interface>
```

Which is being loaded by this simple `main()`:

```
void on_back_clicked(GtkToolButton *button);
void on_forward_clicked(GtkToolButton *button);
void on_up_clicked(GtkToolButton *button);
void on_refresh_clicked(GtkToolButton *button);
void on_home_clicked(GtkToolButton *button);
void on_delete_clicked(GtkToolButton *button);
void on_information_clicked(GtkToolButton *button);
void on_go_clicked(GtkToolButton *button);
void on_location_activate(GtkEntry *entry);
void on_row_activated(GtkTreeView *treeview, GtkTreePath *treepath, GtkTreeViewColumn *column);

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    GtkWidget *window;
    GtkBuilder *builder;

    gtk_init(&argc, &argv);
    builder = gtk_builder_new_from_file("browser.glade");
    window = GTK_WIDGET(gtk_builder_get_object(builder, "applicationwindow1"));

    gtk_builder_connect_signals(builder, NULL);

    gtk_widget_show_all(window);
    gtk_main();

    return 0;
}
```

I also get the following error when the application is run:

```
(browser:4672): Gtk-CRITICAL **: gtk_application_get_menubar: assertion 'GTK_IS_APPLICATION (application)' failed
```

Any hints as to what's going on here on either one?

Comment: It's hard to tell from just a giant Glade file dump. The lack of code and of reference code from the book, makes it very tempting to say "you didn't copy the book right." Can you please trim the Glade file down to the relevant portions, and include some relevant portions of your code?

Comment: One thing that may be breaking your application is that the GTK book is for GTK 2, and your code seems to be using GTK 3.

Comment: ptomato - Indeed, sir. I've been minding the differences as closely as I'm able to, though in this instance I think I just don't know what glade wants me to do. To that point, I've added the main function from this program. It's simply an acquisition of the widgets and connecting the signals (which just print that they've been activated, at present).

Comment: For further clarification: The reason I only put the glade output up was because it does just seem to be a matter of packing details (elements expanding incorrectly). But from what I can tell, the packing options are set correctly.

Comment: Trim your glade file down, nobody will read the giant load of xml:foo.

Comment: Obliged. The only reason I put the whole file up is because I'm not sure what will and won't be relevant.

Comment: Remove things until the issue vanishes. Add things until the issue reappears. If you get to that state, try removing unrelated widgets (like in other subtrees). Then post that _complete_ but shorter gtkbuilder/glade file and I will have a brief look at it.

Comment: Ah, yes. That's a technique I understand but never thought to apply here. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Well, that was silly. As anyone reading now can probably see, I managed to add a 123 pixel bottom margin without noticing somehow. This was my first time using Glade and I was a little tired, so I was quick to panic.

Anyway, thanks to [ptomato](https://stackoverflow.com/users/172999/ptomato) and [drahnr](https://stackoverflow.com/users/188533/drahnr) for pointing me in the right directions.